# Agent stuck with each other

Tags: unity, ai, path-finding, navmesh

As the title. I have stuck on this:
When many agents have same destination, they will be stuck with each other. I want they find a new path as character in the picture a attached below

How can i make agent more clever like this gif bellow. Any one have experiemnt or solution on this? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Can you describe in words what specific "more clever" behaviour you would like your agents to follow?

Comment: Yep .I'm using navemesh and navmesh agent in Unity. When many agents have same destination, they will be stuck with each other. I want they find a new path as character in the picture a attached above